# My Angular app uses a SSO for auth which returns back the user details in header to the application. How to parse incoming header?

Tags: angular, single-sign-on

I built an angular app which uses an SSO for authentication. The users are redirected back to the app home page after getting authenticated from the SSO. However the SSO sets the users details like Name, Email etc in the headers. How can I get the header in the Angular App on loading the very first time?

I have to read the username from the response headers when the Angular application loads and use it to show on my application.

I tried using JWTInterceptor to intercept requests and responses however it only does so for requests that are triggered from the Angular App.

Comment: You would need to parse these headers on the server-side and then inject them into your Angular application. You can do this via Angular Universal, which does your initial render/serve of your Angular app via Node: https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: I use the same technique to pass in environment-specific settings to Angular apps that run in Docker. Our build process sets the environment-specific values, I pick these up in my Angular Universal server.ts file, then pass them to the index.html.

Comment: Did you figure this out? Is using Universal the only way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a component that matches the "redirected back" URL and read the request header.